# Auto Pairing Android BLE stack

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, hid, pairing

I am working on Lollipop 5.1.1_r6 bluedroid stack and have strange situation with HID device. The first step I made is pairing of the peer with host trough Android Settings->Bluetooth menu.

Well, if I restart Bluetooth service first and then erase pairing keys from peer, the host isn't more able to reconnect with peer and keeps old pairing keys. But, if I don't restart bluetooth service before erasing keys on peer, host successfully reconnects to peer.

The only diff between these situations I noticed is that security mask is 0 in case when keys are loaded from NVRAM and

```
tBTA_SEC sec_mask = BTUI_HH_SECURITY; //0x0036
```

when keys are made after

```
bt_status_t btif_hh_connect(bt_bdaddr_t *bd_addr)
```

function.

My question is, is it possible that host can reconnect again with the same peer even if peer erased its pairing keys and user didn't forget peer in Settings->Bluetooth menu of the host before new attempt?

Is this a feature of the standard bt stack on Lollipop?

My understanding is that if host has bonding data it will try to established new connection with the same peer but it should give up if SMP fails or it is up to stack version?

One remarks, peer is whitelisted after successful connection.

Comment: So you basically mean that the host will successfully connect to the peer even though the peer doesn't possess the needed keys? Sounds like a security hole to me...

Comment: Because I am using custom Android davice as a host I tried the same thing on Nexus 9 with Lollipop. Well, repeated all steps (connect, functionality test etc) and then erased keys on peer and wait. After some time (few secs) it seems that peer and host were paired but UHID was not opened in this case. Then I turmed on/off peer and they were reconnected again.